# convert file to python dict

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

Here is my file that I want to convert to a python dict:

```
#
# DATABASE 
#
Database name   FooFileName
Database file   FooDBFile
Info file       FooInfoFile
Database ID     3
Total entries   8888
```

I have tried several things and I can't get it to convert to a dict.  I ultimately want to be able to pick off the 'Database file' as a string.  Thanks in advance.

Here is what I have tried already and the errors:

```
    # ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
    #d = {}
    #for line in json_dump:
        #for k,v in [line.strip().split('\n')]:
    #    for k,v in [line.strip().split(None, 1)]:
    #        d[k] = v.strip()
    #print d
    #print d['Database file']


    # IndexError: list index out of range
    #d = {}
    #for line in json_dump:
    #    line = line.strip()
    #    parts = [p.strip() for p in line.split('/n')]
    #    d[parts[0]] = (parts[1], parts[2])
    #print d
```

Comment: what typr of output are you expecting ?

Comment: so can you add your already tries  to your question !

Comment: How are keys and values defined in your file? What is a key? The first word? First two words? All but the last word? All words in the first 15 characters? All words up to the first multiple space?

Comment: The key is the first column and the value is the second column in my file.

Comment: How is a column defined?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to separate the string after last `#` . you can do it with regular expressions , [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) will do it  :

```
>>> import re
>>> s="""#
... # DATABASE 
... #
... Database name   FooFileName
... Database file   FooDBFile
... Info file       FooInfoFile
... Database ID     3
... Total entries   8888"""

>>> re.search(r'#\n([^#]+)',s).group(1)
'Database name   FooFileName\nDatabase file   FooDBFile\nInfo file       FooInfoFile\nDatabase ID     3\nTotal entries   8888'
```

also in this case you can just use `split` , you can split the text with `#` then choose the last element :

```
>>> s2=s.split('#')[-1]
```

Then you can use a `dictionary comprehension` and list comprehension , note that `re.split` is a good choice for this case as it use `r' {2,}'` for split that match 2 or more space :

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in [re.split(r' {2,}',i) for i in s2.split('\n') if i]}
{'Database name': 'FooFileName', 'Total entries': '8888', 'Database ID': '3', 'Database file': 'FooDBFile', 'Info file': 'FooInfoFile'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answers but I don't know what "re" is in the above answer.

Comment: @user1356863 you're welcome `re` is python modules for regular expressions .

Comment: you can add a line as `import re` to use regular expressions @user1356863

Comment: @user1356863 you just need to put the result of `json_dump` in s variable

Comment: I have tried several times to no avail .... I keep getting the following error when I run from my test.py script:

ValueError: too many values to unpack

Yet it works if I use the python interpreter on the console.

Any ideas???

Comment: @user1356863 use `{ k[0]:k[-1] for k in [re.split(r' {2,}',i) for i in s2.split('\n') if i]}` then give me the result

Comment: @user1356863 and if you found this answer helpful you can tell this to community with voting and accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** to reflect a line-wise regular expression approach.

Since it appears your file is not tab-delimited, you could use a regular expression to isolate the columns:

```
import re

#
# The rest of your code that loads up json_dump
#

d = {}
for line in json_dump:
    if line.startswith('#'): continue  ## For filtering out comment lines
    line = line.strip()

    #parts = [p.strip() for p in line.split('/n')]
    try:
        (key, value) = re.split(r'\s\s+', line)  ## Split the line of input using 2 or more consecutive white spaces as the delimiter
    except ValueError:  continue  ## Skip malformed lines

    #d[parts[0]] = (parts[1], parts[2])
    d[key] = value

print d
```

This yields this dictionary:

```
{'Database name': 'FooFileName', 'Total entries': '8888', 'Database ID': '3', 'Database file': 'FooDBFile', 'Info file': 'FooInfoFile'}
```

Which should allow you to isolate the individual values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it gives an error:

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user1356863 Ah, that likely means that your file is not tab-delimited after all.  I can modify the answer above if you like, but ultimately it is going to look a lot like KasraAD's solution - so I'd recommend you go the regular expression route.

Comment: KasraAD's solution isn't as clear to me as this solution.  I don't know how to tell it to use my file or json_dumps.

Comment: @user1356863 Edited my answer to use a per-line regular expression approach (slightly different to Kasra's approach).

Comment: I am using python 2.7.6 not sure if that matters.  I cut and paste and still get error:

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

on the (key,value) = re.split(r'\s\s+', line)

Comment: @user1356863 Are there any other lines in your file other than what you've included in the post?  Blank lines with nothing on them, perhaps?  I've edited my answer to include a `try`/`except` block to skip any lines that don't match the "expected" format.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when we split, it returns a list of 3 values in it , so we need 3 variables to store the returned results, now we combine the first and second value returned , separated by a `space` to act as a key whose value is the third value returned in the list , This may be the most simple approach but I guess it will get your job done and it is easy to understand as well

```
d = {}
for line in json_dump:
    if line.startswith('#'): continue
    for u,k,v in line.strip().split():
        d[u+" "+k] = v.strip()
print d
print d['Database file']
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately I got the same error as before:

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Then there must be some error in json_dumps, try printing the json_dumps , and edit your question mentioning the output ?

Comment: I tried again and got this error:

>>> d = {}
>>> infile=open("foo")
>>> for line in infile:
...     if line.startswith('#'): continue
...     for u,k,v in line.strip().split():
...         d[u+" "+k] = v.strip()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: what isi the format of the file in which your database data is stored ? is that a `.txt` file ?  or some other format also define the location of that database file ,as to where is it located on your system